# Adding new and already existing data from multiple dataframes into a singular dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Say I have a `main` `df1`:

| Name: | ID | ID2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | 1 | 01 | 100 |
| Robert | 12 | 012 | 80 |
| William | 123 |  | 65 |
| Jul |  | 01234 | 87 |

and then I wanted to add `df2`:

| Name: | ID | ID2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jul | 1234 | 01234 | 87 |
| William | 123 | 0123 | 80 |
| Steven | 12345 | 012345 | 99 |

So in the case where `df1` is my `main` dataframe I want to add the new values from `df2` to `df1`. In the case where the value for `name` in `df1` is new, I want it added to the bottom of `df1` and in the case where the value for `name` does exist in `df1` already I would want the current row to be overwritten with the new `df2` value(s) and stay in the same row that it was prior to the `df2` values being added.

So my final_df would look like this:

| Name: | ID | ID2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | 1 | 01 | 100 |
| Robert | 12 | 012 | 80 |
| William | 123 | 0123 | 80 |
| Jul | 1234 | 01234 | 87 |
| Steven | 12345 | 012345 | 99 |

I have tried:

`pd.concat([df1, df2])`

- But this works for the case where we are adding new data into the dataframe, in the case for adding 'Jul' and 'William' from df2 into our df1 I want it to essentially overwrite the current data that is in df1 for 'Jul' and 'William' since these name values already exists in our df1

Any better solutions? Thank you in advanced

Comment: concat will create duplicates - what if the values differ ?

Comment: if the values differ but the name is the same we would want the value for name that already exists to be overwritten - like for the example of 'Jul' in df2, in df1 'Jul' exists but does not have values for the column: 'ID', but in df2 we have this column and it is new data so we would want 'Jul' to be overwritten with this new data. rather than have it added to the bottom as the concat method is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want df2 values to overwrite df1 values if the `name` is the same, you can `drop_duplicates` by name and keep the row corresponding to the last duplicate (which would come from df2):

```
final_df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset="Name:",keep="last")
```

Result:

```
     Name:     ID     ID2  score
0  Michael      1      01    100
1   Robert     12     012     80
0      Jul   1234   01234     87
1  William    123    0123     80
2   Steven  12345  012345     99
```